# how to show/hide links according to Switch in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to show/hide a breed of links according to the value of a Switch in the UI. I know how to show/hide links when the corresponding procedure is embedded in a setup or go procedure, but I am wondering if I can detach my visible-links procedure in order to call it whenever I want, even if the go button is not pressed:

```
to visible-links
    ifelse show-diffusions? ;; this is my Switch element
    [ask diffusions [set hidden? false]]
    [ask diffusions [set hidden? true]]
end
```

Should I simply add a new button that goes forever and use it to let the user call the visible-links procedure? It would be somewhat ugly, but if that is the only way I'd go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding another "forever" button would be an overkill. There is another solution, but it changes your user interface.

I suppose you have a switch control named `show-diffusions?` which is automatically a global variable in NetLogo. Instead of that switch control create a global variable `show-diffusions?` and a **button** `Show-hide-switch`. The `Show-hide-switch` procedure can switch on and off the diffusions visibility and render the links.

```
globals [
  show-diffusions?  
]

to setup
  set show-diffusions? true
end

to visible-links
  ask diffusions [ set hidden? not show-diffusions? ]
end

; this is called by a button Show-hide-switch
to Show-hide-switch
  set show-diffusions? (not show-diffusions?)
  visible-links
  ; or call display if necessary
end
```